# Puppet master policy-based autosign script STDOUT/STDERR not copied to master's log output

Tags: puppet

According to the puppet master documentation [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_autosign.html#content), both STDERR and STDOUT emitted from the executable referred to by the autosign=[path to executable] setting are copied to the Puppet master's main log output. However, I cannot find this output anywere.

The relevant bit of my puppet.conf:

```
[main]
logdir = /var/log/puppet
log_level = debug

[master]
autosign=/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/autosign.rb
```

The source of /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/autosign.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'etc'

ENV['HOME'] = Etc.getpwuid(Process.uid).dir

STDERR.puts "Inside autosign.rb"
STDERR.puts "====================================="

STDERR.puts "=== ENV['HOME'} ====================="
STDERR.puts "#{ENV['HOME']}"

STDERR.puts "=== STDIN ==========================="
ARGF.each do |line|
  STDERR.puts line if line =~ /login/
end

STDERR.puts "=== ARGV[] =========================="
ARGV.each do |b|
    STDERR.puts b
end

#require 'puppet'
#require 'puppet/ssl/certificate_request'

#clientcert = ARGV.pop

#csr = Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest.from_s(STDIN.read)

retcode = 0
exit retcode
```

Have any of you had success logging from the autosign policy executable? ...or generally in use of this tool?

Comment: Have you tried running a webrick master with `--no-daemonize --verbose --debug` first to get more information? This might clue you in on how things are being logged (or aren't).

Comment: I tested this last night and also found that `stderr` and `stdout` of my autosign policy script was not being logged anywhere.

Comment: I am not sure where the normal logs go, but I can see my debug output in the console with this approach, and this should do the trick..

Comment: @FelixFrank, if you'd like to post your response as an answer, I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes, you can start a standalone master process in a terminal using

```
puppet master --no-daemonize --debug --verbose
```

This should present you with all relevant output.